# IQuery not working for IMultiQuery

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I have IQueries like : (the below IQueries are just dummies for simplicity, infact i have different methods that Creates an Iquery)

```
IQuery q1 = "select q from Quarter where q.QuarterID = :QuarterID";
q1.SetParameter("QuarterID",14);
IQuery q2 = "select m from Month where m.QuarterID= :QuarterID";
q2.SetParameter("QuarterID",12);
```

Then i add them to an Multiquery and execute it :

```
IMultiQuery iMultiQuery = session.CreateMultiQuery();

iMultiQuery.Add(q1);

iMultiQuery.Add(q2);

Ilist _result = iMultiQuery.List();//This gives an error saying :
```

**The named parameter QuarterID was used in more than one query. Either give unique names to your parameters, or use the multi query SetParameter() methods to set the named parameter.**

NOTE: I have Multiqueries in many places. However, before we did not use parameterization for creating an Iquery. Eversince we have started using Parameterized query, I am facing this issue.

[I found the same issue logged here](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2084)

Answer (score 0):

I think the error clearly states the problem you're facing and how to solve it.
Use different parameter-names in your queries that you add to the same MultiQuery, and the problem is fixed.

```
IQuery q1 = "select ... from Quarter q where q.Id = :qid1";
q1.SetParameter("qid1", 14);
IQuery q2 = "select ... from Quarter q where q.Id = :qid2";
q2.SetParameter("qid2", 12);

var mq = session.CreateMultiQuery();
mq.Add (q1);
mq.Add (q2);
```